# Difference between hangout types

Tags: javascript, google-hangouts

I am really unable to know the difference between all hangout types buttons

```
     gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
                'render': 'createhangout',
                'hangout_type': 'normal',
                'initial_apps': [{
                'app_id': '12345', 
                'start_data': id, 
                'app_type': 'ROOM_APP'
                 }); 
     gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
                'render': 'createhangout',
                'hangout_type': 'onair',
                'initial_apps': [{
                'app_id': '12345', 
                'start_data': id, 
                'app_type': 'ROOM_APP'
                });
    gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
                'render': 'createhangout',
                'hangout_type': 'party',
                'initial_apps': [{
                'app_id': '12345', 
                'start_data': id, 
                'app_type': 'ROOM_APP'
                });
    gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
                'render': 'createhangout',
                'hangout_type': 'moderated',
                'initial_apps': [{
                'app_id': '12345', 
                'start_data': id, 
                'app_type': 'ROOM_APP'
                });
```

I know about type "onair" but i don't know what exactly normal , party and moderated buttons will do i.e will they record the video , where the video is saved etc ..,

Answer (score 0):

According to a documentation that no longer exists, but in the [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5anbG4UIrvEJ:https://developers.google.com/%2B/hangouts/button%20&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr), **hangout_type** property means :

> Specifies what type of Hangout should be started. The following values
>   are supported:
>
> **normal**
>       (Default) Launch the Hangout app without broadcasting to YouTube or starting a Hangout party.
>
> **onair**
>       Launch the Hangout to be broadcast on YouTube as a Hangout On Air.
>
> **party**
>       Launch the Hangout app as a Hangout party.
>
> **moderated**
>       Launch the Hangout app with Control Room enabled.